# Ember: When is a controller instantiated

Tags: ember.js

I was going through the Ember tutorial in https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/#toc_storing-and-retrying-a-transition

Here, in order to store and retry a transition, they're setting an instance property `previousTransition` in `loginController`.

How does `controllerFor` work? Will `loginController` not be instantiated again when routed to the corresponding route?

How is `previousTransition` persisted so that they're accessing it in `loginController`?

I'm new to Ember. Could someone throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are singletons in ember.js. A Controller is not instantiated again if a route is reentered. The same applies for Routes. Route provides events, which could be used to reset state on entering / leaving the route.

Comment: If `controllers`, `services` and `routes` are singletons, what are not?

Comment: `Components` are not singletons. They are initialized each time they are rendered. `Models` provided via `ember-data` are another core feature which are not singletons.